# Fire last value when subscribing to publisher?

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, combine

I have an `AnyPublisher` property that emits values. When someone subscribes to it, is there a way to emit the last value immediately and let it listen for future values from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a `CurrentValueSubject` for this and erase that to `AnyPublisher`

```
let publisher = CurrentValueSubject<Int, Never>(1).eraseToAnyPublisher()
let c = publisher.sink(receiveValue: { int in 
  print(int)
})
```

The code above would immediately print `1` since that's the current value of the `CurrentValueSubject`.

Comment: How to avoid this behavior? I.e. ignore the first value on subscribe?